# Реализация логирования и последующее считывание из лога

Tags: алгоритм, php

Доброго времени. Нужно реализовать лог следующего вида:

```
<месяцгод>07.11<\месяцгод>
   <день>01<\день>
      [id][description][date_entered];
      ...
   <день>02<\день>
      [id][description][date_entered];
      ...
   <день>dd<\день>

<месяцгод>08.11<\месяцгод>
   ...

<месяцгод>mm.yy<\месяцгод>
   ...
```

А потом считывать информацию по месяца и дням. Как это грамотно реализовать и с помощью чего? Т.е. например записывать в текстовый файл а потом создать функцию, которая будет искать нужную позицию и возвращать "[id][description][date_entered]; ..." по каждому дню месяца? Или есть более удобная реализация, XML?

Comment: `<месяцгод>07.11<\месяцгод><день>01<\день>` А какой смысл у такого для xml, если день не относится к месяцу?) Тогда уж `<месяцгод значение="07.11"><день значение="01" id="01-07-11" date_entered="???">description</день></месяцгод>`

Comment: Предположил. Хочется узнать простую реализацию, потому что грамоздкую уже придумал.

Пока не знаю как удобнее сделать, ну в общем смысл такой, чтобы было легко находить в логе записи по конкретным дням (записей будет несколько в день)  месяца.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простая реализация

```
$message = array(
  'id' => 15,
  'date' => '01.07.2011',
  'message' => 'raz raz raz'
  )
function placeMessage($logfile, $msg) {
  if (!$f = @fopen($logfile, 'a+')) return false;
  fwrite($f, $msg['date'].'#'.str_replace("\n", '##N##', serialize($msg)));
  fclose($f);
  return true;
  }
function getMessage($logfile, $date) {
  $result = array();
  if (!$f = @fopen($logfile, 'r+')) return $result;
  while ($str = @fgets($f)) {
    list($dateMsg, $msg) = explode('#', $str, 2);
    if ($date == $dateMsg) $result[] = unserialize(str_replace('##N##', "\n", $msg));
    }
  fclose($f);
  return $result;
  }
```

А вообще да, в вашем случае БД больше подходит (если возможность есть).

Answer (score 1):

Для логирования лучше подходят простые текстовые файлы. Для форматирования логов можно воспользоваться встроенной реализацией [`fputcsv()`](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

```
$log = array(
    time(),
    '127.0.0.1',
    'Some message'
);

$fp = fopen('application.log', 'a');
fputcsv($fp, $args);
fclose();
```

И соответственно поиск:

```
$from = strtotime('2011-15-06');
$to = strtotime('2011-15-07');

$fp = fopen('application.log', 'r');
while ( ($log = fgetcsv($fp)) ) {
    if ($log[0] < $from) {
        continue;
    }

    if ($log[0] > $to) {
        break;
    }

    $log[0] = date('r', $log[0]);
    vprintf('[%s] %s: %s', $log);
}
fclose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Если хранить в файле, то лучше избавится от лишней информации, присущей формату ХМЛ (хранить в CVS), чтоб не тратить время на парсинг данных:

```
--year;month;day;id;description;date_entered;
2011;03;12;01;Hello Word;''
```

Если все же хочется хранить в XML, то стоило бы привести его к более приемлимому виду:

```
<year value="2011">
  <month value="01">
    <day value="15">
      <!-- вариан А -->
      <item>
        <id>a</id>
        <desc>b</desc>
        <date>c</date>
      </item>
      <item>
        <id>a2</id>
        <desc>b2</desc>
        <date>c2</date>
      </item>    
      <!-- вариан Б -->
      <item id="a" desc="b" date="c" />
      <item id="a2" desc="b2" date="c2" />
    </day>    
    <day value="16">
      ...
    </day>    
  </month>
  <month value="02">
    ...
  </month>
</year>
```

Ежу понятно, что названия тегов лучше выбирать покороче, чтоб сократить общий объем данных, а также время, затраченное на их разбор и считывание. Поэтому такой вариант будет более оптимален:

```
  <item year="x" month="y" day="z">
    <id>a</id>
    <desc>b</desc>
    <date>c</date>
  </item>
```

или

```
<items year="x" month="y" day="z">
  <item id="a" desc="b" date="c" />
</items>
```

Вы можете легко обрабатывать ХМЛ с помощью xpath, но если вам этот вариант не подходит, можете поискать средства, которые позволяют работать с ХМЛ как с БД (к сожалению, не помню названий).